# How to combine multiple if statements into one

Tags: c

I want it to make a single `if` statement to check both the `name` and `familyname` variables.

I want my statement to be somthing like this:

```
if(strcmp(name && family name , "first" /* how can i do here??? */ ) == 0){}
```

My current code looks like this:

```
if (strcmp(name , "MyName" ) == 0 ){
    if (strcmp(familyname,"Myfamilyname") == 0){
        printf("Name:%s %s is Verified!\n", name , familyname);
    }
}
```

Comment: Larger arrays, `strcpy` and `strcat`?

Comment: Hint: any next `if` can be replaced with `&&` in the previous `if`, if there are no `else` parts.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie. And sometimes even then if you are clever enough.

Comment: You should select whichever answer helps you the most. That is standard procedure. It will help you build rep as well as us. It is good to have rep on this site if you are getting into programming since reputation will determine the tools that are available to you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `&&` operator:

```
if(!strcmp(name, "MyName") && !strcmp(family_name, "MyFamilyName")) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

C's logical operators (`&&` and `||`) support short-circuiting. This means that once the value of the expression is known, the remainder of it is not evaluated. For example, if the first `strcmp` evaluates to non-zero (the first name does not match), the second comparison won't be done at all since there is no way for the expression to be true at that point. This can be used to check for things being `NULL`, for example: `if(name != NULL && !strcmp(name, "blah")) ...`

The `!` operator is logical not, which converts any non-zero value into a zero and any zero into a one. (This is different from binary not `~`, which flips all the bits individually: `!5 == 0`, but `~5 == -6`). `!strcmp(...)` is therefore a shorthand for `strcmp(...) == 0`.

Any logical expression of the form `!A && !B` can be recast as `!(A || B)`. This is one specific example of [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws), which generally make your code reading easier. In light of this, your `if` statement can be rewritten as

```
if(!(strcmp(name, "MyName") || strcmp(family_name, "MyFamilyName"))) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

which is the way @Boiethios wrote it.

Comment: Thanks, much more complete than my answer :)

Comment: Yes, I did not forget about operator precedence, OP did.

Comment: @Boiethios .. ok man .. i watch too many videos on youtube .. i really like this c programming especially .. many people like you and the rest is willing to help and give me more knowledge and idea!! – Xriel Zz just now

Answer (score 2):

Just do 2 `strcmp` as you did:

```
if ((strcmp(name, "MyName") || strcmp(family_name, "MyFamilyName")) == 0) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

Use the binary or operator `||` so that if one of the return values is different from zero, the whole result is also different from zero.

Comment: It's not good idea use bitwise operators, when logical `||` will do. Bitwise operator doesn't have short circuit evaluation.

Comment: @user694733 That is true, thank you, I edited my answer.

Comment: ah its called bitwise okay ill try this logical one

Comment: @XrielZz *binary or* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C

Comment: It should be a && operator not a || operator for the logic to work

Comment: Hey man i got a problem when i put the wrong name variable and right familyname variable it will proceed to the rest of my code , but when i put the right name and wrong family name it will go through else.

Comment: @XrielZz Hum, I tested, it works. Maybe you forgot some parenthesis.

Comment: oh the code i posted to still not work it will go through else

Comment: @XrielZz as I said, you forgot parenthesis. Bad recopy. See the Mad Physicist's answer and consider accepting it, it is more complete than mine.

Comment: Mad. As in completely insane. Although I do have a background in GIS, so that works too.

Comment: @Boiethios im sorry man now the code you give is working ... ilove you i love you i love you ,.. thank you all mua mua mua

Comment: @XrielZz You're welcome, don't forget to read Mad Physicist's answer and accept it to enhance your knowledge.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie. I did. I'd like to know who downvoted this correct solution? It is a perfect example of where De Morgan's laws can take you...

Comment: @Mad Physicist, yes...I must have been lost in logic somewhere.

Comment: @Boiethios .. ok man .. i watch too many videos on youtube .. i really like this c programming especially .. many people like you and the rest is willing to help and give me more knowledge and idea!! – Xriel Zz just now

Comment: @PaulOgilvie. I made an edit, so you can reverse your vote now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the combined conditions

```
if ((strcmp(name , "MyName" ) == 0 ) && (strcmp(familyname,"Myfamilyname") == 0)){
    printf("Name:%s %s is Verified!\n", name , familyname);
}
```